# Calling a method on the main thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, multithreading, methods

First of all I am writing code for iphone.
I need to be able to call a method on the main thread without using `performSelectorOnMainThread`.
The reason that I don't want to use `performSelectorOnMainThread` is that it causes problem when I am trying to create a mock for unit testing.

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@Selector(doSomething) withObject:nil];
```

The problem is that my mock knows how to call `doSomething` but it doesn't know how to call `performSelectorOnMainThread`.

So Any solution?

Answer (score 302, accepted):

**Objective-C**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self doSomething];
});
```

**Swift**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.doSomething()
}
```

**Legacy Swift**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.doSomething()
}
```

Comment: You just made my day with the swift 3 code. Thanks!

Comment: It is good practice to not use self directly into block. instead use weak reference of it.

Answer (score 2):

There's a saying in software that adding a layer of indirection will fix almost anything.

Have the doSomething method be an indirection shell that only does a performSelectorOnMainThread to call the really_doSomething method to do the actual Something work.  Or, if you don't want to change your doSomething method, have the mock test unit call a doSomething_redirect_shell method to do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better way to do this in Swift:

```
runThisInMainThread { () -> Void in
    // Run your code
    self.doSomething()
}

func runThisInMainThread(block: dispatch_block_t) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block)
}
```

Its included as a standard function in my repo, check it out: https://github.com/goktugyil/EZSwiftExtensions

Comment: This is not better in any way, you created a function that does nothing but calling another one. by the way that swift syntax can be further simplified "() -> Void in" is not needed

Comment: Its more human readable/writable. Yes autocomplete adds in "() -> Void in". Is there anyway to disable this autocomplete behavior in void>void closures?

Comment: the method name you have could be misleading, it sounds like the block would be executed right away on the main thread, but that's not true. dispatch_async on main queue adds the block of code to the next runloop, this important behavior is hidden behind the method that is called "runThisInMainThread

Comment: and I haven't found a way to configure Xcode to follow the simplified syntax :(

Comment: http://pastebin.com/gReE6Wyr I tried it, you are correct. It not only adds the code to the next runloop, it also delays stuff after it. Why is this happening?

Comment: this is the expected behavior, dispatch_async adds the code to the end of the queue. If you want it to get called right away you should do dispatch_sync instead. If you do dispatch_sync on a queue for the thread that you are already in it causes a thread lock. in your example the order of prints are "a", "c", "b". a and c are getting executed in 1 runloop because they are in the same scope. b is added to the end of the queue so it gets called sometimes later when the other existing items in the queue are completed

Comment: so what is a legit way to run something in the background without locking a thread?

Comment: @Esqarrouth - are you SURE your `dispatch_async` blocked code after the call to it?  The entire point of using `async` rather than `sync` is to NOT block what follows.  (Of course, the `block` of code WILL block anything else *on the main thread*, since the point of the asked-for code is to execute on the main thread.  If you want to run background code, then you would ask for a different queue, not `dispatch_get_main_queue`.)

Answer (score 1):

And now in Swift 3:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
   self.doSomething()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The modern Swift solution is to use actors for safe multithreading, namely the `MainActor`.

```
@MainActor func setImage(thumbnailName: String) {
    myImageView.image = UIImage(image: thumbnailName)
}
```

I've outlined more actor-based main thread solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67893377/4995828).

Answer (score -4):

```
// Draw Line
    func drawPath(from polyStr: String){
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let path = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: polyStr)
            let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
            polyline.strokeWidth = 3.0
            polyline.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.05098039216, green: 0.5764705882, blue: 0.2784313725, alpha: 1)
            polyline.map = self.mapVu // Google MapView
        }

    }
```