# hide a button on checking a condition while the app enters foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiview-hierarchy

I have to hide a button by checking two particular viewcontroller's view is a descendant of present view.This is being done when the app comes to foreground.
Code:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationWillEnterForeground) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil] ;


(void)applicationWillEnterForeground
{
   if(!([hrViewController.view isDescendantOfView:self.view] || [reportViewController.view isDescendantOfView:self.view]))

{
[self.theFavouriteButton setHidden:YES];
}

}
```

And the problem is ,Eventhough the view presented while coming to foreground is hrViewController.view  or reportViewController.view,the control is reaching inside the if condition and which is hiding my button.Why is this so?

Comment: Why does it have to be done in the app delegate?

Comment: Sorry I didnt get you..

Comment: Why not do the work in the view controller itself; perhaps observing `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`?

Comment: try wrapping your setHidden in a GCD Main block (help here on GCD main blocks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606145/calling-a-method-on-the-main-thread)

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint to see which condition is true?