# Swift task is not running on main actor as expected

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency

I have the following code in a simple Mac test project:

```
@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
  func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    print("are we initially on the main thread: \(Thread.isMainThread)")

    Task {
      print("is new task on main thread: \(Thread.isMainThread)")
    }
  }
}
```

In the [Swift language guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html#ID643), I see the following:

> To create an unstructured task that runs on the current actor, call the Task.init(priority:operation:) initializer. To create an unstructured task that’s not part of the current actor, known more specifically as a detached task, call the Task.detached(priority:operation:) class method.

So since the AppDelegate code is running on the main actor and I'm creating a normal (i.e. non-detached) task, I'd expect its child task to also run on the main actor.

But that's not what happens when I run this test app:

```
are we initially on the main thread: true
is new task on main thread: false
```

Based on what I've read about Swift concurrency, I expected the new task to be scheduled and run on the main actor and that `Thread.isMainThread` would therefore be true inside that task.

Why is that not the case?

Comment: I don't know for sure, so I'll leave it to one of the concurrency wizards - but I think that even though it's dispatched on `DispatchQueue.main` it's not necessarily on the `@MainActor`. Some of `UIKit`/`AppKit` has been annotated with main actor, but not the app delegate for example [(reference)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67893377/9607863). I would love to know the real answer though

Comment: A useful answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67954900/9607863), with this excerpt: "``But `test1` is not marked for any special thread. `test1` _itself_ runs on the main thread, because it is _called_ on the main thread; but it is not _marked_ to run on the main thread. Therefore its Task operation falls back to running on a background thread.``". I'll leave it to matt on this one, if they see this

Comment: @George Hmm I think you're right. It's not explicitly annotated as being on the main actor. If I put a `@MainActor` annotation right before my definition of `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, then I _do_ get the expected output. It's still a bit strange, because I thought being on the main thread implied that any new tasks would be on the main actor - instead, they seem to default to detached tasks, which is weird.

Comment: For the sake of writing it in the same place, [this](https://twitter.com/dgregor79/status/1458656417825505284) Twitter thread about this topic may be a good quick read-through

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What determines whether a Swift 5.5 Task initializer runs on the main thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67954414/what-determines-whether-a-swift-5-5-task-initializer-runs-on-the-main-thread)

Answer (score 0):

The important distinction to be made here just running code on main thread doesn't mean code is running on `MainActor`. To have your method always run on `MainActor` you can make the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method isolated to `MainActor` with `@MainActor` attribute. In swift concurrency, if you make methods/properties isolated to an actor any Task you create inside them with `Task.init` will also inherit the actor context. Currently you don't have your actor isolation specified and hence seeing this behavior.

Comment: My log statement is already checking for the main _thread_ not for the main _actor_...

Comment: The idea is that Task inherits the Actor trait - but the delegate method not marked as @MainActor may not be executed with the MainActor trait in the system so that the new Task will inherit something else or nothing.