# Xcode giving warning when using await UIApplication.shared.open(settingsURL) in Swift async function

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-concurrency

I am calling `await UIApplication.shared.open(settingsURL)` inside a Swift `Task` but I am getting an Xcode runtime warning:

> UIApplication.open(_:options:completionHandler:) must be used from the main thread only

```
Task {
    guard let settingsURL = await URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) else {
        return
    }
    await UIApplication.shared.open(settingsURL) // <-- runtime warning when called
}
```

The SDK shows these methods:

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
open func open(_ url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:], completionHandler completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
open func open(_ url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) async -> Bool
```

The error message implies that it thinks I'm using the first, non-async one (because of the mention of the completion handler), but I'm not. `UIApplication` is marked with `MainActor` so my understanding is everything called via an instance of `UIApplication` is run on the main thread automatically. This works just fine for other things I've called on `UIApplication` elsewhere such as `isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications`.

The app runs fine, no crashes or anything, just the warning from Xcode.

Is Xcode just confused here or am I actually doing something wrong?

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot of error]

EDIT: for those confused about `MainActor`, this is a useful read: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/the-main-actor-attribute/

I can just wrap `UIApplication.shared.open(settingsURL)` in `await MainActor.run` but I'm still confused why `MainActor` doesn't work here / why Xcode thinks the wrong method is being called.

Comment: `URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)` is not an `async function` (it's just an optional), so there is no need to have `await` before it.

Comment: The await there is because of the UIApplication. Won't compile without it. Doesn't affect the question either way. Could be any URL.

Comment: Possibly relevant thread: https://twitter.com/dgregor79/status/1458656417825505284

Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70065630/swift-task-is-not-running-on-main-actor-as-expected

Comment: "I can just wrap UIApplication.shared.open(settingsURL) in await MainActor.run but I'm still confused why MainActor doesn't work here / why Xcode thinks the wrong method is being called." Well, that's what my answer told you. It's a bug! But you kept rejecting that so I deleted it.

Comment: Huh? I didn’t reject anything, what do you mean?

Answer (score -1):

The error indicates you may be using `Task {...}` somewhere in your code that is not on the main thread.
With the following test code, I could not replicate your issue, using  macos 12.3 Beta, Xcode 13.3,
targets ios 15 and macCatalyst 12. Tested on real devices, not Preview. It may be different on older systems.

This is the code I used in my tests:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("testing")
            .onAppear {
                Task {
                    guard let settingsURL = URL(string: "https://duckduckgo.com") else { return }
                    await UIApplication.shared.open(settingsURL) // <-- NO runtime warning when called
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Does this code give you the same warning?

EDIT-1: this also works for me.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("testing")
            .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                    Task {
                        guard let settingsURL = URL(string: "https://duckduckgo.com") else { return }
                        await UIApplication.shared.open(settingsURL)
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: The thread the `Task` is run on shouldn't matter. [`MainActor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mainactor) is supposed to ensure that the calls to `UIApplication` are executed on the main thread. If I were running my task on the main thread there wouldn't be any issue in the first place, but moving execution to the main thread is not a solution. Note, downvote not mine.

Comment: fair enough comment. However, in my code, I can wrap the `Task{..}` in a background task using `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { Task {..} }` 
and still work well for me. See updated code.

Comment: I copied your new code and put a breakpoint on the `await` line, it still says `Thread.current` is the main thread. Maybe the system sees the only `await` call is a MainActor and thus the whole task is optimized at runtime to run on the main thread? Not sure yet.

Comment: Change `Task` to `Task.detached` and you will see the issue in my question.

Comment: ha yes, with `Task.detached` the issue is clear.